# jQuery.each(function(index, value){}); What is value?

Tags: jquery

I am learning jQuery from a book called [Head First jQuery](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfjquery/). The book is very easy to learn from. The point is, there is an `.each()` function(included in image which I scanned from the ) which has a function() parameter. The function() parameters are `index` and `value`. The index is explained on the page, but what about the value? And also, since it is an anonymous function(which cannot be reused) how does it take any parameters?

Comment: And who says anonymous functions can't take parameters? :)

Answer (score 19):

There are two `each` methods in jQuery. One is for cycling over a jQuery object which contains many matches. For instance, suppose we wanted to find all paragraphs on the page:

```
$("p").each(function(){
    // Do something with each paragraph
});
```

Secondly, there is a more generic  `each` for iterating over objects or arrays:

```
var names = ["Jonathan", "Sampson"];
$.each(names, function(){
    // Do something with each name
});
```

When jQuery cycles over the elements in either of these examples, it keeps count of which object it's currently handling. When it executes our anonymous function, it passes in two parameters - the current value we're on (index), and that object (value).

```
var names = ["Jonathan", "Sampson"];
$.each(names, function(index, value){
    alert( value + " is " + index );
});
```

Which outputs "Jonathan is 0", and "Sampson is 1" since we're using a zero-based index.

But what about our native jQuery object?

```
$("p").each(function(index, value){
    alert( value.textContent ); // The text from within the paragraph
});
```

In this case, `value` is an actual `HTMLParagraphElement` object, so we can access properties like `textContent` or `innerText` on it if we like:

Comment: So `value` is the object and not the `value` property? By `value` property I mean just like in an `input` there is a `type` property which can be `button`, `submit` and so on there is a `value` property for `input` types too.

Comment: @cadence441 Yes, the `value` is the element. This could be an HTML element, or this could be a string. Or it could be an array, an object, or number - it depends on the collection you're cycling over. And note that the variable names `input` and `value` don't matter - only the order does. You'll often see people only include `index`, or they'll use both under different names, like `i` and `v`.

Comment: so in the last example, "value" is the same as "this" ?

Answer (score 1):

This second paremter which you called value is the **value** of the collection that is currently processed by the each function.

For your second question - anonymous functions can be reused, just because they don't have a name doesn't mean they can't have parameters or be executed. See following example:

```
function execute_fn(fn) {
  fn(1,2);
}

execute_fn(function(a,b) { ... });
```

Comment: Does **value of the collection that is currently processed** mean this?:-
$(".myClass").each(function(index, value) {  });
And we have:-
<input type="button" class="myClass" value="Button"/>

Comment: ...continued
<input type="submit" class="myClass" value="Submit"/>
So the value of the first element will become "Button"?

And is (fn) jQuery defined or user-defined? I mean that the .each() function is jQuery defined. Just like that is (fn) jQuery defined?
If it is user-defined, we don't pass anything as the parameter fn, right? And same for (a,b) right?

Comment: In your example in the first execution value would be the DOM-element of the button (so would be this; in each-functions the second parameter and this point to the same object) and the next time it would be the DOM-element of the submit button.
Regarding my example: it should only demonstrate how a anonymous function can be executed by a different function. It doesn't use jQuery at all.
I recommend you to read up about JavaScript basics. JavaScript may look like C++/C/Java but it is very different.

Comment: When I tried this code `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  div { color:red; text-align:center; cursor:pointer; 
        font-weight:bolder; width:300px; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" class="lol" value="try a"/>
  <input type="submit" class="lol" value="try b"/>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".lol").each(function (value) {
         alert(value);
      });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>` it showed up the index and not the value. Why?

Comment: First parameter is always the index. Second parameter is always the value. It doesn't matter how you name them. Use function(index, value) { ... } instead of function(value) { ... } and just don't use the index parameter if you don't need it.